# Unable to change text positioning for navigation bar

Tags: html, css, frontend

For the code, please visit http://coloradohypnosis.com.s51572.gridserver.com/

In the nav bar, I cannot get the text to be center aligned for the nav items such as "Home", "What Others are Saying", "What to Expect", etc.

The current alignment skews the design slightly.  I've played around with Chrome's Developer tools to change the CSS in the browser, but nothing I did changed the text's alignment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to change the left and right padding to be of the same value, this way it will add the same padding on the left and right section to center align the text in your anchor element. For example:

```
#nav ul li a { padding: 34px 0.5em 18px 0.5em }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting the `a` tags to be `text-align:center` and `display: block` then add equal left and right padding to the a tags. Maybe set the `li` tags to be `text-align:center` too just to be sure :p

Answer (score 0):

change your anchor padding in your style.css (line 41):

```
#nav ul li a
```